# theme error in makestyles inside material-ui v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was making some react components and make styles.js for each of the following. i am learning from a YT tutorial who is using material-ui version4. so i upgraded it to V5.

**Code for the component (Form) =**

```
import React from 'react'
import useStyles from './styles';


const Form = () =>{
    const classes = useStyles();

    return(
        <h1>
FORM
        </h1>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

**code for the styles.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin:  theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  paper: {
    padding:  theme.spacing(2),
  },
  form: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  fileInput: {
    width: '97%',
    margin: '10px 0',
  },
  buttonSubmit: {
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
}));
```

**The error i recieved**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD0U9.png)

Is there any simple fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully, it says ***You are providing a function without a theme in the context. One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.***, so, you need to make sure you've a theme provider wrapped for a parent to make this work. Check [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#themeprovider) guide for how you can add a theme provider.